# Mirror the movement of one object to another

Tags: mirror

In an animation I move an object, e.g. a plane, on a manually created path. Now I want to mirror this movement onto another object, also a plane. The mirror modifier doesn't seem to be the right tool for me. How do I proceed?

Thanks
Leo

Comment: Hello and welcome. Maybe constraints could do it, but how are placed the several object and where is the mirror center?

Comment: I think you'd have to copy the bones and reasign them to the other mesh.

Answer (score 3):

The *Copy Location* and *Copy Rotation* constraints have an invert option.

[image]

The top instance is on a path constraint, the bottom instance has the constraints shown, targeted on the top one. You may have to alter the axes to suit the orientations of your objects, and your choice of mirror plane.

The result is mirrored action (in this case in the XZ plane)..

[image]

Comment: Great explanation. It took me a while, but I was successful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a copy of the animated object
2. Parent the copy to an Empty
3. Set the scale of that Empty to X -1 (or other axis)
4. Play

When you make a copy of an object you will get a copy of the animation as well. 
By parent the object you can control it's local coordinate system. When the empty is scaled across the X axis you make a mirror world for that object and it's animation.